# Pytorch 0.4.1 invalid gradient at index 0 - expected shape[] but got [1]

Tags: python, pytorch

I've been around this problem for the whole day.

`torch.autograd.backward(loss_seq, grad_seq)` will get an error.

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_vgg.py", line 272, in <module>
    torch.autograd.backward(loss_seq, grad_seq)
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py", line 90, in backward
    allow_unreachable=True)  # allow_unreachable flag
RuntimeError: invalid gradient at index 0 - expected shape [] but got [1]
```

Input:

```
loss_seq:[tensor(7.3761, device='cuda:1', grad_fn=<ThAddBackward>), tensor(4.3005, device='cuda:1', grad_fn=<ThAddBackward>), tensor(4.2209, device='cuda:1', grad_fn=<ThAddBackward>)]
grad_seq:[tensor([1.], device='cuda:1'), tensor([1.], device='cuda:1'), tensor([1.], device='cuda:1')]
```

```

Can someone tell how to fix it?

---

input code:

```
images = Variable(images).cuda(gpu)

label_yaw = Variable(labels[:,0]).cuda(gpu)
label_pitch = Variable(labels[:,1]).cuda(gpu)
label_roll = Variable(labels[:,2]).cuda(gpu)

pre_yaw, pre_pitch, pre_roll = model(images)

# Cross entropy loss
loss_yaw = criterion(pre_yaw, label_yaw)
loss_pitch = criterion(pre_pitch, label_pitch)
loss_roll = criterion(pre_roll, label_roll)

loss_yaw += 0.005 * loss_reg_yaw
loss_pitch += 0.005 * loss_reg_pitch
loss_roll += 0.005 * loss_reg_roll

loss_seq = [loss_yaw, loss_pitch, loss_roll]
grad_seq = [torch.ones(1).cuda(gpu) for _ in range(len(loss_seq))]

# crash here
torch.autograd.backward(loss_seq, grad_seq)
```

Comment: If you can share what is the tensor that goes into `loss_seq` and `grad_seq`, people will be more likely to help. Guessing what goes in is not a good idea.

Comment: Yes, I have already added

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem. Only change:

`grad_seq = [torch.ones(1).cuda(gpu) for _ in range(len(loss_seq))]`

to:

`grad_seq = [torch.tensor(1.0).cuda(gpu) for _ in range(len(loss_seq))]`